# My CSS will work in every browser but not ie8, the layout of it all goes funny and displays wrong

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

Some of my CSS wont work in IE8 but will work in chrome,firefox,IE11.

I first made the website on chrome and then realized it didnt work in ie11 so I put code into the html like the code below...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

After putting this, my website works on ie11. Later to find out, that it does not work on ie8.

I am making this website for my company and all around the company ALL the staff use different browsers, so I need to make sure it works on all.

Do I have any hope? or do I have to give up on this one? I have researched all over google about everyone different code inserts they put in for it to work on ie8 but it doesnt work.

In my CSS im using stuff such as border-radius and box-shadow and many many more.
Is there an alternative... to say, "if you are using ie8 to display this website, display this piece of code differently to suit the browser."

Thanks

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or codepen and demonstrate the problem so others can offer help.

essentially you could use a conditional stylesheet for IE8 and/or modernizr to address the IE8 layout issues.

Comment: The Microsoft browsers are very well known to cause issues with CSS styling and especially to introduce new issues from version to version. They never seem to get it right. The bottom line is: you may have to invest a huge amount of time to support such an old browser which is not maintained any more even by its producer and some issues might even be impossible to fix. Welcome to the hell of cross browser issues cause by incomplete implementation of standards.

Comment: Note that IE8 is outdated and does not support most HTML5 functions, see this: https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-8.html

Comment: For checking your website compatibility with different version of different browsers, you can go here: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots

Comment: IE8 is so outdated that Microsoft no longer provide security updates for it (nor do they provide security updates for operating systems that can't run a newer version of IE). If people in your company are running IE8 their systems should be considered a security threat and the IT department should upgrade them to something supported.

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically looking for is "graceful degradation". Check out some articles about that here:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement
http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/graceful-degradation

In any case, keep in mind that making a modern page work on IE8 is a tedious task, and most likely unnecessary. The global market share for IE8 is currently around 1%, so you really have to consider if you do that extra work.

Comment: This website will not be global, its a intranet page within a company and company will see this, and all computers have different browsers. Thanks for you help though. 

Will this take long to fix?

Comment: Well that depends on the size of the page etc. yes, this might take long to fix. (fix meaning there is a page that "works" in IE8). You should probably tell that company that using IE8 in 2016 is a massive security risk.

Comment: I completely agree that ie8 is stupid. But apparently it will take them years to upgrade ie8 into ie11 because it takes ages to update on all the different computers.

So I have around 20 pages in my website, they are all reasonably the same just have different content in. What exactly am I doing to make it work on ie8? dont really understand this graceful degradation